# How do I change my development environment to a different language in Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio, development-environment

When I first installed Visual Studio, I chose to customize my environment for "Visual C++" development. Now, I am working primarily in C# and want to change this setting to a C# environment.

How can I change the environment settings from one language to another in Visual Studio?

Answer (score 62):

Tools → Import and Export Settings → Import Selected Environment Settings...

A dialog will appear, prompting you whether or not you want to save your current settings. If you've made extensive customizations and might want to go back to them at a later date, you should choose to save them.

Then click "Next". You'll be prompted to import a set of environment settings. At the top will be the default environment settings options, customized for each language. In your case, you'd choose C#.

If you wanted to re-import your saved settings, you'd do it the same way—just browse to the saved settings file in the final step of the wizard.

Comment: To add on, if you want to retain your current color scheme, under 'Environment' deselect "Fonts and Colors". This will retain all current color schemes. Recommend scanning other selections as well in case there is a customization you would like to keep, because selecting the "C#" environment essentially takes you back to default settings for everything.

Comment: I don't see have any options under Default settings for c#.

Answer (score 9):

You could also [reset all of the settings from the command line](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms241273.aspx):

```
devenv /resetsettings
```

And then choose all over again when prompted.

Note: I prefer "General Developer Settings" if you are going to do development in different technology areas (C++, C#, VB, etc.).

Comment: Thank you for this answer. Very helpful. So I could create a link for each of commonly used configurations.