# Why is Visual Studio 2010 pretty-printing in C++ mode while stepping through C# code?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, c++-cli

I am encountering a strange issue. i have all the latest updates in my PC. My OS is Windows 7. Can anyone help me out with this? I have tried resetting the Visual studio.

[image]

And here is the exact problem blown up to make it easier to see:

[image: Close-up on the problem]

Comment: "Why is the debugger pretty-printer running in C++ mode while stepping through C# code?", apparently

Comment: Can you show the call stack window also please?  It has a column for Language that might be, well, interesting.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I change my development environment from C++ to C# in Visual Studio 2008?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/967309/how-do-i-change-my-development-environment-from-c-to-c-sharp-in-visual-studio)?

Comment: @CodeCaster That's an entirely different question: choosing the C++ settings has no effect on debugging C# code. (I prefer the C++ keybindings, even when I'm dealing with C# code.)

Comment: Have you tried disabling addins to see if the issue goes away?

Comment: Did you attach with a mixed mode debugger?

Comment: What's the C++ syntax? I'm not seeing it.

Comment: @EstebanAraya `System::Collections::Specialized::NameObjectCollectionBase^`

Comment: This was reported as a bug:  [visual studio debugging c# as c++](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/540228/visual-studio-debugging-c-as-c), but apparently it was reproduced.  You might see if you can reproduce the issue using the Visual Studio 11 Beta; if you can, it would be worth opening another bug for the issue.  I agree, this is most unusual.

Comment: I've gone ahead and added a blow-up so that people can see the problem without assuming hexadecimal is something specific to C++...

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why does debugging a C# project display C++/CLI symbols?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9910622/why-does-debugging-a-c-sharp-project-display-c-cli-symbols)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the issue by re-installing the OS. 
But I do remember that i was installing lot of software while i was installing the Visual Studio that. might have corrupted the OS file

Answer (score 3):

I had the exact same issue. To confirm, look in the call stack at a c# stack frame. For me it said C++ instead of C#. For anyone else with this problem:

I fixed it by looking at the compatibility settings for VSLauncher.exe, Devenv.exe, and the shortcut to Devenv.exe. One of them (VSLauncher.exe) has compatibility mode set to Windows XP. I turned that off and it was fixed.

Answer (score 2):

The Hex display is because you chose that option (clicked on the toolbar), click on it again to switch back to the normal display. The C++/CLI type is not related to the Hex dispaly issue though.

[image]

Comment: This explains the hexadecimal literals.  Does this explain the C++/CLI syntax type names?

Comment: Hex display would not make his types display like `System::Web::HttpValueCollection`...

Comment: No actually it does not, I am looking into reproducing that as well. I am guessing it should be debug settings.

Comment: The original poster is not asking about hexadecimal, as they selected it intentionally. Not sure why this is still an answer.

Comment: I did try with unselecting the HEX button too. was not successful

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this issue as well, the debugger picked up c# and c++ in all c# projects.  I'm running windows 7 64 bit.

I resolved this issue by going to the compatibility tab of the properties of the shortcut.
It was checked as running as windows xp service pack 3.  I unchecked that and still kept run as administrator checked.  Suddenly my debugger picked all of it up as c# again.