# Tools.Settings menu missing in Visual Studio 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio

I have recently switch from c# to C++ & assembler but I am unable to view the registers or memory windows because I am unable to check the **Expert Settings**. This is because my tools menu, the traditional route of access, has no **Settings** option. Instead, there is an **Import and Export Settings** option. This is normally a sub menu of **Tools.Settings**. Has anybody had the same experience and solved it or does anybody have an alternative strategy to accessing **Expert Settings**?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about an issue with a 3rd party tool

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I change my development environment to a different language in Visual Studio?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/967309/how-do-i-change-my-development-environment-to-a-different-language-in-visual-stu)

Answer (score 0):

Inside "Import and Export Settings", you should have a "Reset Settings" option. Within that, choose either the "C++" or the "General Developer" settings. All your advanced menus/tools will come back. You can selectively apply only menu settings, shortcuts, etc. so your other customizations are not wiped out.